# Series that converges while the sequence doesn't necessarily decrease

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This might be a kind of stupid question but I can't seem to get my mind around it so I hope someone can help me.

There's this statement that says:

> "If $a_n > 0$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$, the series
>   $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\cdot a_n$ converges if and only if
>   $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence".

I know this is false but I can't seem to find any example that contradicts it.

Thank you in advance to everyone.

Comment: For a cheap counterexample you can just rearrange finitely many terms in your favorite alternating convergent sum.

Comment: @lulu Since this question is about existence and not value of convergence, it really should've said "$a_n$ is an _eventually_ decreasing sequence". That would've been a more reasonable statement. Still false, but at least immune to cheap tricks like yours.

Comment: @Arthur  Agreed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the nondecreasing sequence:

$$1, 2, 1, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \ldots$$

It's easiest to see the pattern and the convergence if you look at the terms 3 at a time.

Answer (score -2):

First, your title, "series that converges while the sequence doesn't" is impossible.  One of the first things one should learn about series is that "a necessary (but not sufficient) condition that the series $\sum a_n$ converges is that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ **converges to 0**.  That is not a "sufficient condition" because there exist examples of sequences that converge to 0 while the series does not converge $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ is such an example.  However, for **alternating** sequences, $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ it is both necessary and sufficient that $a_n$ converge **to 0**.

Comment: Yeah I edited that as soon as I figured out I wrote it wrong.

Comment: What is written here is not accurate.  For alternating series (or any series) to converge it is necessary that the terms go to $0$ but that is not sufficient.  For an alternating sequence if you have the (absolute) terms decreasing to $0$ that is sufficient to imply convergence, but it is not necessary.

Comment: As an example of a divergent alternating series $\sum (-1)^na_n$ with $a_n>0$ and $\lim a_n=0$ consider $a_{2n}=\frac 1{n^2}$, $a_{2n+1}=\frac 1{n+1}$.  The positive (even) sum converges absolutely but the negative (odd) sum diverges.

Comment: Please edit or delete this post.  The statement "for **alternating** sequences, $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ it is both necessary and sufficient that $a_n$ converge **to 0**" is a standard student error and it should be corrected.

Comment: You might want to consider my example above, and compare it to your last sentence, which is both false and misleading.